# How to efficiently hide and show

Tags: keyframes, geometry-nodes, visibility

I'm trying to show / hide a multitude of mouth models to simulate talking (because the face has such poor geometry that a facial rig isn't possible).

Here is an image listing all the mouth models:

[image: mouth models]

I know that you can press `i` to insert a keyframe when you're hovering over visibility options, but that takes wayyy too long considering I cant copy and paste the visibility keyframes.

So I just want to know if there is a more efficient way of simulating talking by showing/hiding mouths instead of creating a facial rig.

Another thing I'm looking at is making an addon that does just that. I know a very small bit of python and not enough to make my own add-on so if there are any good resources to learning add-on creation that you know about I would appreciate it if you linked them.

Another idea that I think would be able to make this work is doing something with geometry nodes maybe?

[Here is the blend file](https://drive.google.com/drive/folders/1ad1JJCdHJHas006mlwiiBiS31PehVbCB?usp=sharing) - let me know if textures are needed.

Also please let me know if any other info is needed.

Thanks!

Comment: *"I can't copy and paste the visibility keyframes."* there's plenty of options depending on what exactly is your problem... [auto keyframe](https://docs.blender.org/manual/en/latest/animation/keyframes/editing.html#auto-keyframe), [keying sets](https://docs.blender.org/manual/en/latest/animation/keyframes/keying_sets.html), [drivers](https://docs.blender.org/manual/en/latest/animation/drivers/index.html)...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

### version Auto-Keyframe

At frame one add keyframe to all expresions ... and enable Auto-keyframing

[image]

... now the only one thing you have to do is to show/hide object in Outliner.

BTW ... you can copy&paste or duplicated&move keyframes of visibility in **Dope Sheet**
(to se also unselected objects disable cursor icon).

[image]

### version Driver

As pointed by Markus in comment ... you can manage mouth expressions by drivers. You can use another object's location or rotation (or what ever) to control show/hide appearance.

Here is object visibility controled by bone rotation ...

[image]

[image]
[image]

[image]
[image]

[image]
[image]

By right click you can Copy-Paste driver from Scene to Render visibility ...

[image]

[image]

Note: By default drivers use rotation value in radians (even blender UI is set and displays degrees). Since it is more natural to use degrees use for angle 45° `radians(45)` or `45*(pi/180)` ... scripted expression for Cube in this example looks like

```
0 if ((var > radians(-45)) and (var < radians(45))) else 1
```

... this tells blender to display Cube in bone range -45 to 45.